# NodeJS is faster than D when computing prime numbers. How?

Tags: node.js, performance, time, d, primes

I wrote a simple function for computing prime numbers in D. I thought it was pretty quick, calculating prime numbers up to 100,000. But then I wanted to compare it to NodeJS. When I ran the NodeJS script for the first time, I was astounded at the difference and double checked I wasn't skipping some sort of calculation some how. But the two are pretty identical functionally.

D:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.math;
import std.datetime;
import std.file;
import std.array;

enum size_t ITERATIONS = 100_000;

bool divisible(real n) {
    real d;
    for(d = 3; d < floor(n / 2); d += 2) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void main() {
    StopWatch sw;
    size_t T = ITERATIONS;
    size_t C = 0;
    real n = 2;
    real r[ITERATIONS];
    r[C] = n;
    sw.start();
    C++;
    for(n = 3; n < T; n += 2) {
        if(!divisible(n)) {
            r[C] = n;
            C++;
        }
    }

    sw.stop();
    double seconds = cast(double)sw.peek().usecs / 1_000_000;
    writeln("\n\n", C, " prime numbers calculated in ", seconds, " seconds.");


    File file = File("primes.txt", "w");
    file.writeln("\n", C, " prime numbers calculated ", seconds, " seconds.");

    foreach(number; r[0..C]) {
        file.writeln(number);
    }

    file.writeln("\n", "end");
    file.close();
}
```

NodeJS:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var ITERATIONS = 100000;

function divisible(n) {
    var d;
    for(d = 3; d < Math.floor(n / 2); d += 2) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

(function() {
    var buffer  = [ ],
        now     = Date.now(),
        C       = 0
        n       = 2
        ;

    buffer.push(n);
    C++;
    for(n = 3; n < ITERATIONS; n += 2) {
        if(!divisible(n)) {
            buffer.push(n);
            C++;
        }
    }

    var time    = Date.now() - now,
        seconds = time / 1000
        ;

    console.log("\n\n", C, " prime numbers calculated. Process took ", seconds, " seconds.");
    buffer.push("\n" + C + " prime numbers calculated. Process took " + seconds + " seconds.");

    fs.writeFile("node_primes.txt", buffer.join("\n"), function(err) {
        if(err) throw err;

        console.log("Primes have been written to file.");   
    });
})();
```

Results:

```
Calculating 100,000 primes:
D:      3.49126 seconds
NodeJS: 0.652 seconds
```

Can anybody explain why this is happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Compiler and command line for D?

Comment: I'm using `dmd /path/to/source.d` to compile.

Comment: Try with `dmd -O -release -inline -boundscheck=off /path/to/source.d`.

Comment: Nope. Same results. Saved no time whatsoever.

Comment: It's hard to believe that writing a bunch of numbers to a file could affect performance that much, but now I'm curious. I wonder if there are any I/O benchmarks on both ends.

Comment: The thing is, the StopWatch in D is not timing the writing of the file, but instead, just the actual calculation. The same goes for the Node script, it doesn't time the file IO, just the calculations.

Comment: OK, with the tips from the answer, I set `ITERATIONS` to 1,000,000 and the results speak for themselves. NodeJS: 61.177 seconds. D: 31.1313 seconds.

Comment: And to those who were wondering about file I/O: my benchmark shows better results with D. Writing a million new-line separated integers in a single string to a file yields 0.004804 seconds in D and 0.03 seconds in Node.js, in my machine.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Thanks for the info, I was just assuming knowing nodeJS un-blocking file IO, but I don't know enough about D to compare (so it was a really out on the limb guess). I removed my comment so I'm not spreading any false information.

Comment: @E_net4, writing 10,000,000 characters to a file (≈10MB) took 0.032904 seconds on my machine.

Remember, it's not JUST the language that dictates the speed of file IO. The kernel and file system are also two big factors, and not to mention, most fundamentally, the disk. I have an SSD in my 2013 MBP.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo I completely understand what non-blocking I/O means. Please don't assume people are clueless in what they are talking about.

Comment: @thephpdev Indeed, there are many factors. However, considering that the tests were executed in the same machine under similar circumstances, as well as with many trials, I've identified some overhead in the language/framework's implementation.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I am not assuming anything, not even saying that you are clueless. Simply your comment _" I was just assuming knowing nodeJS un-blocking file IO, but I don't know enough about D to compare"_ makes me think you are making some confusion here.

Comment: dmd's floating point optimizer is pretty bad. The integer optimizer is pretty good, but float/double/real aren't optimized well at all. Using gdc might give speedups, or switching to ints with dmd will probably make a big difference too.

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe, unfortunately, GDC is not available for OS X.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By unnecessarily declaring variables as `real`, you are **forcing floating point arithmetic where integer arithmetic could be used**. Replace all instances of `real` with `int`, get rid of that `floor()` and your D program will run as fast as the Node.JS version:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.math;
import std.datetime;
import std.file;
import std.array;

enum size_t ITERATIONS = 100_000;

bool divisible(int n) {
    int d;
    for(d = 3; d < n / 2; d += 2) {
        if(n % d == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

void main() {
    StopWatch sw;
    size_t T = ITERATIONS;
    size_t C = 0;
    int n = 2;
    int r[ITERATIONS];
    r[C] = n;
    sw.start();
    C++;
    for(n = 3; n < T; n += 2) {
        if(!divisible(n)) {
            r[C] = n;
            C++;
        }
    }

    sw.stop();
    double seconds = cast(double)sw.peek().usecs / 1_000_000;
    writeln("\n\n", C, " prime numbers calculated in ", seconds, " seconds.");


    File file = File("primes.txt", "w");
    file.writeln("\n", C, " prime numbers calculated ", seconds, " seconds.");

    foreach(number; r[0..C]) {
        file.writeln(number);
    }

    file.writeln("\n", "end");
    file.close();
}
```

Comment: That must've hit the mouche. I tried that code against Node.js and obtained around 1.8 of speedup.

Comment: Hi, that solved it. I was not aware that using real was forcing floating point operations to be used. But interestingly enough, removing the Math.floor() from NodeJS caused it to run 0.12 seconds slower avg..

Comment: `real` in D is defined as the floating point type with the largest precision. This means it was potentially the slowest number type you could have chosen. On the other hand, the V8 runtime may perform optimizations on number operations. For instance, it may use integer operations when it is known that whole numbers are used.

Comment: @E_net4, I see, I used real because that was the variable type that the floor function used. I just didn't realise that it was [probably] the slowest type I could have used haha. Well, we've all gotta learn one way or another.

Comment: Well, positive integer division will round them down by default anyway. ;)

Comment: @E_net4 which is a problem for negative numbers. `floor()` is equivalent to truncation only for positive numbers, just try https://gist.github.com/anonymous/93d77f3e5e4ff2bfba1f to see the difference.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Precisely why I specified "positive integer division", which is the case here.

Comment: @E_net4 somehow I did not see the "positive" part. Guess it still stands as a complement to your comment.

Comment: FWIW, on a number of systems, `real` maps to "the only FP type the CPU can a process" so the only slowdown (vs. `float` and `double`) is in I/O and memory bandwidth (including register spills). IIRC Intel was one such system before it got all the vector operations.